# vue-recaptcha element on my form is not visible

Tags: vuejs2, captcha

In my Laravel 5/vuejs 2.6 I  imported https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha ,
I registered at site and got app_key and Site Key and Secret_Key.
I inserted code at my vue form, there is no errors in the condole, but captcha element is not visible on my form.
I followed the instructions as made small form :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-5 row_content" style="border: 2px dotted green; ">

            test_recaptcha::{{ test_recaptcha}}
            <vue-recaptcha
                sitekey="6LfI0bQUAAAAAPp4DXULsAZBoWPImkMFNwhosVJl"
            >
            </vue-recaptcha>


        </div>

        is_page_loaded::{{ is_page_loaded}}<br>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import Vue from 'vue';

    import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';  // https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha

    Vue.component('vue-recaptcha', VueRecaptcha);

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                message: '',
                show: false,
                is_page_loaded: false,
                test_recaptcha:null,
            }

        },

        name: 'test',
        // mixins: [appMixin],

        components: {
            VueRecaptcha
        },


        computed: {

        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Test Component mounted.')

        },

        methods: {
            recaptchaVerified(response) {
                console.log("recaptchaVerified response::")
                console.log( response )

                this.pleaseTickRecaptchaMessage = '';
                this.is_recaptcha_verified = true;
            },

            recaptchaExpired() {
                this.pleaseTickRecaptchaMessage = '';
                this.is_recaptcha_verified = false;
            },



        },

    }

</script>
```

My page looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rci1t.jpg

But I suppose that vue-recaptcha is on my page, say if in tag

```
app.js?dt=1566989208:128808 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "sitekey"
```

Why I do not see vue-recaptcha on my page ?

package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "crosshttps://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.15",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.19.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.3.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.3",
        "marked": "^0.7.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.0.2",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.5",
        "vee-validate-laravel": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
        "vue-color": "^2.7.0",
        "vue-easy-slider": "^5.2.10",
        "vue-focus": "^2.1.0",
        "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
        "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.28",
        "vue-jstree": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.7",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.16",
        "vue-recaptcha": "^1.2.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-select": "^2.6.4",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.0.33",
        "vue-stepper": "^1.4.2",
        "vue-upload-component": "^2.8.20",
        "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^2.11.2",
        "vue2-filters": "^0.6.0",
        "vuejs-paginate": "^2.1.0",
        "vuex": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```